# F5 - URL redirect without irule

Tags: web-application-firewall

I have a main domain - url which is getting load-balanced through VIP between 2 Real Servers in F5 and I want a sub-domain of the main url not to be loadbalanced but to be pointed to  a single real server but with the same Virtual IP. How can we do this without irule in F5? Any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [HTTP class](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/8000/000/sol8018.html) for this. You will need to create a new pool with just that single real server in there and use the HTTP class to direct traffic to your subdomain to that pool.

Comment: Hi.. Can I use the same real server for the main domain as well as url redirect. When I try to create a new pool with the same real server i am  not able to do that.

Comment: Yes, servers can be in as many pools as you want.

Comment: HTTP classes are deprecated beginning in 11.4 and you will need to use a Local Traffic Policy instead going forward. Upon upgrade, these will be converted for you unless you are using an iRule.